# Ubuntu 22.04 is released and posts about it are no longer off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

Now that [22.04 is released](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-April/000279.html), questions pertaining to it are no longer off-topic (due to the version) as of Thu Apr 21 17:09:48 UTC 2022; however, they may still be closed for other reasons. *New* 22.04 questions should not be closed *for being about 22.04*. Of course, posts still need to be on-topic (see [the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)), just being about 22.04 is no longer a valid reason to close a question.

This does not mean that older (i.e., before release) questions about 22.04 can be reopened without discussion/community consensus. Questions about 22.04 that were published prior to the release remain off-topic unless the community decides on a case-by-case basis that a specific post should be re-opened.

Comment: @andrew.46 Just to be perfectly clear: Is it correctly understood that questions about *Upgrading from 20.04 or 21.10 to 22.04* are also **on-topic**, even though the upgrades are not rolled out immediately, and the upgrade path for 20.04 to 22.04 isn't *official* before the first point release in August? *(you currently have to apply the `-d` flag, even though you upgrade to the final version)*

Comment: It was unclear from the comments on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404436/unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-22-04-from-ubuntu-20-04) if 22.04 upgrade questions are OK, but there have been quite a few of them, so I believe it's fully on-topic.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I agree with you completely:  questions about upgrading from 20.04 or 21.10 to 22.04 are on-topic in Ask Ubuntu. I believe that when Canonical gives a release date and time for a major release that is the date and time that *all* questions are on-topic for that major release (with the usual caveats). As for the update issues currently being experienced that has been nicely answered here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404011/57576 and hopefully '*in the next couple of days*' this will be sorted...